# how to combine two probes to a new probe or a new predicates in Z3?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I have two probes in z3 for example

```
p1 = z3.Probe('num-consts')
p2 = z3.Probe('num-exprs')
```

and I want to combine these two Probe to the form such as p1/p2 or p1-p2 in a branching statement such as If(), but I don't know how to implement this.

```
import z3
p1 = z3.Probe('num-consts')
p2 = z3.Probe('num-exprs')
t = z3.If(z3.BoolVal(p1/p2 > 2), z3.Tactic('simplify'), z3.Tactic('factor'))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the goal to the composite tactic. Here's an example:

```py
import z3

p1 = z3.Probe('num-consts')
p2 = z3.Probe('num-exprs')

def t(g):
    return z3.If(p1(g)/p2(g) > 2, z3.Tactic('simplify'), z3.Tactic('factor'))

x = z3.Int('x')
g = z3.Goal()
g.add(x > 0)
g.add(x < 10)
print(t(g)(g))
```

This prints:

```
[[x > 0, x < 10]]
```